# How to insert function $.UI.create label into Global js file

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building a simple app in appcelerator.

I use this code to create a Label with style from **tss** file.

```
function createHeader(headerText){
   var heading = Ti.UI.createView({
      backgroundColor : "#0c7b84"
   });

   var headingText = $.UI.create("Label", {
       classes: 'headerTableLabel'
   });
   headingText.text = headerText;

   heading.add(headingText);

   return heading;
}
```

The headerTableLabel class is declared in app.tss file

```
".headerTableLabel" : {
    color : "#FFF",
    font : {
        fontSize : "13pt",
        fontWeight : "Bold"
    },
    textAlign: "left"
}
```

Now I want to insert the createHeader function in my Global.js, so in this mode I can call this function from all controllers of my application.

But if I try to cut and copy this function (that works) in Global.js file, I have an error at **$.UI.create**

> Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   Source:     var headingText = $.UI.create("Label", {
>   [ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at common/Globals.js:5: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The `$` scope doesn't exist outside of controllers.

You're trying to use a class, outside of a controller scope. This won't work because `tss` doesn't live in the app. Both `tss` and `xml` files are compiled into a single `js` file during compile. It also looks at all your `$` code in the controller and attaches the correct styling to it so you don't have to manually copy-paste it into dynamically creating views.

Because your file is outside of a controller, it can also be called at a later stadium, and the compiler doesn't know where to get `tss` from, because in every controller you can override and apply custom styling.

I recommend making a separate controller for just the view, or manually add styling to the dynamically created view in your `Globals.js` file. I have written a blog about how to do that and how you can talk to it. In my apps I try to avoid dynamically creating any views. https://medium.com/all-titanium/enhancing-titanium-organising-the-big-view-files-20c1237223f2#.3oaij58n9